# video not working on mobile and is not centered from marker (AR.js)

Tags: ar.js

I have several problems, the first one: when you hover over the marker, the video is not displayed on mobile devices, I just see a black square and that's it.
The second problem is that I am unable to stretch the a-video to the full width of the marker and position it in the center.
Thank you all in advance!

My code:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aframevr/aframe@1c2407b26c61958baa93967b5412487cd94b290b/dist/aframe-master.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js"></script>
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    AFRAME.registerComponent("videohandler", {
      init: function() {
        var marker = this.el;
        this.vid = document.querySelector("#vid");
        this.vid.pause();

        marker.addEventListener(
          "markerFound",
          function() {
            this.vid.play();
          }.bind(this)
        );

        marker.addEventListener(
          "markerLost",
          function() {
            this.vid.pause();
            this.vid.currentTime = 0;
          }.bind(this)
        );
      }
    });
  };
</script>

<style>
  .arjs-loader {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 9999;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .arjs-loader div {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color: white;
  }
</style>

<body style="margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;">
  <div class="arjs-loader">
    <div>Loading, please wait...</div>
  </div>
  <a-scene
    vr-mode-ui="enabled: false;"
    renderer="antialias: true; alpha: true; precision: mediump;"
    arjs="trackingMethod: best; sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false;"
  >
    <a-assets>
      <video
        src="https://cdn.glitch.com/8383ce4d-10be-4440-a143-97d71674e0a3%2FHARU%20%E2%80%93%20%D0%92%D0%9A%D0%98%D0%9D%D0%9E%20(Mood%20Video).mp4?v=1630088605215"
        preload="auto"
        id="vid"
        response-type="arraybuffer"
        loop
        crossorigin
        webkit-playsinline
        autoplay
        playsinline
      ></video>
    </a-assets>

    <a-nft
      videohandler
      type="nft"
      class="nft"
      url="https://cdn.glitch.com/8383ce4d-10be-4440-a143-97d71674e0a3%2Fnar"
      smooth="true"
      smoothcount="10"
      smoothtolerance="0.01"
      smooththreshold="5"
      raycaster="objects: .clickable"
    >
      <a-video
        src="#vid"
        scale="1 1 1"
        position="0 0.1 0"
        rotation="-90 0 0"
        class="clickable"
        gesture-handler
        width="208"
        height="208"
      >
      </a-video>
    </a-nft>
    <a-entity camera></a-entity>
  </a-scene>
</body>
```